# jquery push array into array and maintain keys (multidimensional?) in post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to $.post with some form data as well as some other data in an array. I am able to push the array into the rest of the formdata but I lose the keys from they array and the data is just represented as a string, I guess what I'm asking for is a multidimensional array?

Here is the response string currently:

```
array(3) { ["ban_type"]=> string(11) "Account ban" ["ban-duration"]=> string(1) "2" ["test"]=> string(19) "adsasdasd,usertest2" }
```

The ['test'] is the array i'm trying to pass. Here is the data I am passing where 'getSelectedUsers()' is the array:

```
   var formdata =   $('#ban-form').serializeArray();
   formdata.push({name:'test', value:getSelectedUsers()});
```

Is there anyway I can get the value of ['test'] to hold the actual array with keys?

EDIT: here is the post used in a function:

```
$.post(action, request_data, function(data)
{
   $(response_element).html(data);
});
```

and here is the call with the data passed:

```
       ajaxPost(action, formdata, "body");
```

if I just pass the array I get the response with keys:

```
ajaxPost(action, {test:getSelectedUsers()}, "body");
```

EDIT: for clarifcation on what I am asking - Is there any way I can append/push a normal array into the serialized formdata array such that it is multidimensional and can hold the array and it's keys rather than just the string: ["test"]=> string(19) "adsasdasd,usertest2" (I need the keys e.g [1] => 'usertest2' so that I can access them later?)

Comment: Does `getSelectedUsers()` actually return an array? What do you do with `formData` after the lines shown?

Comment: Added clarification in edit and yes getSelectedUsers() returns an array. I use formData in a $.post

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if the question was unclear, solved by manually creating the array rather than trying to serialize the form data and appending the array:

```
var data = 
   {
     form_data:
     {
         ban_type: type,
         ban_duration: duration
     },
     ban_data: getSelectedUsers()
   };
```